# Orchard 1.10 build failed using VS2015 with lots of dll error

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I downloaded orchard (Orchard.Source.zip) and unzipped it. Then I opened using Visual Studio 2015. When I was trying to build, getting lots of error (286 errors). Most of those are .dll related error as it is unable to figure out the dll.

[image]

Extra steps which I tried to resolve:

1. I updated all NuGet packages but still no luck. :(
2. Tried to build each project manually but not working
3. tried to change Target framework to .NET Framework 4.5 or other versions. but no luck

I am not sure, whether I missed anything? If you know what are the steps I am missing, can you please mention. Or if I need to do any more steps, please let me know.

**Software I used:** 
 - VS2015 Enterprise [version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3] 
 - Orchard 1.10.1
   [from orchardproject.net/download and I used [Download the source]
   version]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet was not properly updating the references. So, I was getting those error. To solve all those errors, I manually updated to the missing packages and finally it solved.

One other alternative solution, you may try is: **Right click** on the Project, choose **Mange NuGet Packages** and then update all the required packages.

Hopefully, it will solve the errors. And you will be build the project successfully....

:)

[image: solution of missing packages]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the newest updates for VS2015? Like Update 3? You can get it from here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129

From where do you downloaded the source? http://orchardproject.net/ ? I recommend for you to double check the zipped file, and try to unzip it again. A lot of things could be wrong with it.

Comment: I am using VS2015 Enterprise [version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3].  I downloaded Orchard from http://orchardproject.net/download   and I choose [Download the source] version

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962432/visual-studio-refuses-to-build-project-due-to-missing-assembly-reference-that-is