# User Control Class Library C# "Some assembly references are missing."

Tags: c#

This Bug Affect's the Designer, which makes the entire project useless without it, it happends in Visual Studio 2019 and in 2022, I haven't checked 2020 or lower versions of Visual Studio, It's not an error, but it seems to fail to load the Xaml Designer, With it saying **"Some assembly references are missing."** **"Building to restore the NuGet cache might resolve this issue."** which I don't know what it means.

Reference Image

[image: 1]

This happends everytime you create a `User Control Class Library | c#` template project, as I have searched  in the internet and found nothing because it would not work as these Answers would in most of the time would not work:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/i-continue-to-get-an-error-stating-some-assembly-r/305807
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad5de1a1-e54d-435a-b98f-6f70bef91635/wpf-core-quotsome-assembly-references-are-missingquot?forum=wpf
- [Visual Studio refuses to build project due to missing assembly reference that isn't missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962432/visual-studio-refuses-to-build-project-due-to-missing-assembly-reference-that-is)

^^^ These don't work,

**If There is no definitive answer / solution to this problem it is a Major Visual Studio Problem/Bug** For C# Assembly Developers.

Comment: Did you try building? I hear it might resolve the issue by restoring the NuGet cache.

Comment: Works just fine when I try it in VS2019 v16.11.16 targeting .NET 5.0 and VS2022 v17.1.5 targeting .NET 6.0.  Ensure your VS version is up to date by running the Visual Studio Installer.  Try temporarily disabling the installed security software next, the designer runs out-of-process and that makes it vulnerable to over-eager anti-malware.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on Windows 10 version 2004 (build 19041) and had same issue.

App was a (first time) new blank MAUI app (VS 2022 v17.9) and rebuilding did nothing obvious to change the behavior.

In the Application Properties, I switched to Windows 10 version 2104 (build 20348) and got an error (it seems that version is really Windows 11) so I switched back to build 19041 and the View Designer worked.

Go figure - multiple versions are a test matrix nightmare!