# C# Visual Studio Build Errors of not being able to find a dependencey project build/DLL but it's there in /bin and its build is successful

Tags: c#, dll, build, namespaces, build-error

Getting 243 build errors that are all variations of: **"The type or namespace name 'Missing_Project' could not be found (and you are missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"**

Screencap: https://postimg.cc/ctnH62qD

--

"Missing_Project" is the second last project to build and when I clean-build itself, there are no errors. It seems to build fine. It's when I try to build the next project (Let's call it "Next_Project") that these errors appear telling me "Missing_Project" could not be found.

What I know for sure:

- "Missing_Project" is building successfully
- "Next_Project" needs "Missing_Project" and can't find it

--

What I've tried:

- checked /bin for the relevant DLL, it's there as expected -- this confirms the build
- deleted contents of /bin and then clean-build
- checked references for Next_Project to contain Missing_Project and removed it then re-added it as a reference
- checked the dependency versions
- checked my mapping to the right branch and pull the latest
- check that I don't have pending changers open in local
- deleted the entire branch and re-cloned it clean
- run Visual Studio in admin; checked I'm logged in properly

I don't know what else to do. This is a major blocker. Spend a couple hours screen-sharing with seniors at work who also couldn't figure it out (yet) but we plan on trying again tomorrow morning.

Also, this really weird thing where if I click the error and open the file, the error itself will disappear as if it's resolved (but it's not).

Maybe relevant: This happened after pulling latest.

Has this happened to anyone?

Comment: You may want to check the specified frameworks for the various projects, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450999/are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference-compile-error-visual-studio ... and ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962432/visual-studio-refuses-to-build-project-due-to-missing-assembly-reference-that-is