# How to fix : IndexModel could not be found in asp core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have an Razor Page application with asp core 2.1.
it was work fine one year ago.
today I opened it and tried to build it.
it give me these errors

[image]

in andex.cshtml.g.cs

```
   public IndexModel Model => ViewData.Model;
```

Comment: Have you checked the assembly reference? Does it look all right?

Comment: where to check?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450999/are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference-compile-error-visual-studio ?

Comment: Have you defined `IndexModel`,or you missing `using xxx.xxx.IndexModel`(using directive)?